# Intuit Anywhere Development versus Production Authentication/Authorization

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I am successfully using OpenID and OAuth in development mode.  Once I am ready to move to Production will the process change in a way that the authentication/authorization process will not require manual intervention?  Today I click on the "signin" button to authenticate using OpenID.  I then click on the "Authorize Quickbooks" button to authorize using OAuth.  During these two processes I am redirected to Intuit where I click on buttons to allow authentication/authorization.  Will I be able to achieve this process through code?  I am working on a SaaS application and need to authenticate/authorize in code because the manual steps will not work with the application I am working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the free trial on a couple of the apps in the app center to see what they are doing. I tried out eBillity, their app picks up OpenID and OAuth without user interaction during the subscription process.

Based on that, yes, I think you can achieve it all in code. Personally I have not been able to get the OAuth tokens without user intervention.

Update: Use this JS method to do the OAuth authorization during the subscription process:
http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0060_Reference/JavaScript_Functions/directConnectToIntuit

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I am looking for a more technical answer.  I am specifically wondering if my .Net code needs to be structured different for Production, so that there is no manual intervention needed to authenticate/authorize.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I did see the directConnectToIntuit code.  I have tested this and it does trigger the OAuth process (simulating the "Connect to Quickbooks" button being clicked on the client application), but the user is still redirected to Intuit where they are still required to click on "Authorize" on the Intuit side.  I am assuming this is the way it is meant to be implemented (the directConnectToIntuit code).

Comment: Direct Connect is only needed after an OpenId flow, which is only needed when a user signs up from the Intuit Appcenter. His app is not going to be on Appcenter so he only needs the Oauth 3 legged flow...no openid needed, no direct connect needed.

Answer (score 3):

Your app should work the same way in development as in production.

Make sure you have gone through the requirements checklist - http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0010_Getting_Started/0040_Publishing_Your_App/0010_Reviewing_the_Requirements_Checklist

There are different requirements if you are just doing the Connect to QuickBooks flow or you are also wanting to be listed on Appcenter.

Comment: Is there documentation/sample .Net code available on just implementing the "Connect to Quickbooks" flow?  The goal is not needing manual authentication/authorization.  The application will not be available in the AppCenter.

Comment: Even when you are connect to quickbooks only, the customer must click on the connect to quickbooks button, enter their credentials, select their company file and authorize your app.

Comment: Thanks Jarred, if clicking on "Connect to Quickbooks" button is the only thing needed to be able to surface Quickbooks data to a SaaS application why would you include, or want to include, the "Sign in with Intuit" button?  What added functionality do you get back including that signin button?

Comment: That sign in button is not needed unless you are using openid, it allows a user of your site to login with their Intuit openid instead of the sites identity. Sort of like login with Facebook on cnn.com